# Downloading remote image to local device is not listed in the Photo Library

Tags: react-native

I am developing a React Native application. Now, I am trying to download a remote image into the local device.

This is my code:

```
downloadFile = () => {
    var date = new Date();
    var url = 'https://static.standard.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2016/05/22/11/davidbeckham.jpg?w968';
    var ext = this.extention(url);
    ext = "." + ext[0];
    const { config, fs } = RNFetchBlob
    let PictureDir = fs.dirs.PictureDir
    let options = {
      fileCache: true,
      addAndroidDownloads : {
        useDownloadManager : true,
        notification : true,
        path:  PictureDir + "/image_"+Math.floor(date.getTime() + date.getSeconds() / 2)+ext,
        description : 'Image'
      }
    }
    config(options).fetch('GET', url).then((res) => {
      Alert.alert("Success Downloaded");
    });
  }

  extention = (filename) => {
    return (/[.]/.exec(filename)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(filename) : undefined;
  }
```

I am following this tutorial, https://medium.com/@derrybernicahyady/simple-download-file-react-native-2a4db7d51597?fbclid=IwAR1XR75fivHPtE8AfpXKUuFdaLIOehii4ahI4u0lMVgu7ee62yVmnqDnd04. When I run my code, it says the download was successful. But when I checked my photo library, the image is not there. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Use [CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll#savetocameraroll) method for this instead.

Comment: DocumentDir will add it to the app's internal directory it won't add it to the photo library of the iOS device.

Comment: Hi. I looked at it. But CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll is only for local uri. Not for remove URL. Can you provide me the code simple using CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll for remote URL, please?

Comment: First use RNFetchBlob to download the image to a temporary directory first, then save it to camera roll using CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll, then remove the image using RNFetchBlob.